# Compare URLs via window.location.host?

Tags: javascript, url, comparison, window.location

I'd like to compare the URL of the current webpage. My first idea was to use    window.location.host :

```
if (window.location.host == example.com) {
    //code to be executed if condition is true
}
```

But this doesn't work. Any other ideas?

Oh well, I'm not much schooled with javascript. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do what you said. Just remember to put string literals in quotes.

```
if (window.location.host == "example.com") {
    //code to be executed if condition is true
}
```

Comment: @PatrickLenz don't forget that you can reward someone who's helped you by marking their answer as the solution to your problem by clicking the checkmark next to it.

Comment: Sorry. I'm new to stackoverflow ;)